# How to control relay via MSP430

Tags: msp430

Using MSP430F66736A, embedded programming, Code Composer 6.1.0

In my app i need to control a relay which is on 2 pins(P5.0- STATE1 and P5.1- STATE2). P4.6 is LED.

It should work like that:

Led is OFF for specific time(for example 2 sec), relay should get t STATE1,
after specific time(3 sec for example) LED is ON and relay should switch to STATE2

What´s wrong with that code? LED is blinking as I wish, but relay is not working(can´t hear any ticking)

This is not full code, just specific lines with configurating P5(relay)

```
 LOOP(doesnt matter)
if (P4OUT == 0x00)
        {
            cyklus = cyklus + t1;   
            P5DIR |= BIT1;
            P5OUT |= BIT1;
            P4OUT ^= BIT6; 
            TA1CCR0 += (sekunda*t1);

        }
        //opakovaci cas odpojenia
        else
        {
            cyklus = cyklus + t2;   
            P5DIR |= BIT0;
            P5OUT |= BIT0;  
            P4OUT = 0x00;
            TA1CCR0 += (sekunda*t2);
```

Comment: Why do you have two pins for the relay? Is it double throw?

Comment: Show the schematic of the circuit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence it is **not** a hardware issue, nor is enough information about the hardware given.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the interfacing of the relay. Have you checked the datasheet of relay that you are using? Relays are current controlled switches and MSP430 controller might not be able to provide enough driving current to the relay because of which the relay would not be latching on (ticking sound that you hear), although it blinks the LED.
You might need to add a switch like a BJT or MOSFET for this purpose along with a higher voltage.